# DAG creation in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

In Apache Spark, I know that when I use some transformation functions all the functions are stored as DAG and when I call an action Spark runs all the required transformation functions from that DAG till the Action function. 
So, suppose I have

- Step1. 3 transformation functions
- Step2. 1 action
- Step3. 4 transformation functions which uses output of above action.
- Step4. 1 action

So, my question is after the calling of first action at step 2, does the dag gets deleted and when second action is called new DAG is created  from step 3 or is the new DAG created from step 1?

Comment: Can you explain some sample actions whose output you would like to use in Step 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark uses Resilient Distributed Datasets (RDD), which represent a collection of data. Spark can store it in distributed memory. RDDs are built in a DAG, as you mentioned.

In your case:

- In the first Action, the computation from DAG is computed, and it results in the RDD.
- In step 3, this newly created RDD is used as an input of a new DAG.
- In step 4, this DAG is computed, and it results in the final RDD.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So you mean to say after the computation at  step 2 DAG from Step 1-2 will be deleted and only the value of output RDD at step 2 will be used further and the new DAG will be created for only STEP 3-4. Spark will not recompute the value from Step 1. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: I do not know (and not find it important) if the old DAG will be technically deleted. What is important, that Spark will not recompute the value from Step 1, but will work with the output of the first Action. You are right. This technique is called Lazy Evaluation.

Comment: Thank you so much, This was what I wanted to clarify. I was getting problem an error because I had put an action after many transformation functions, so it was giving me stackoverflow error and also some tree error. So. when I used some actions in between to reduce the length of DAG, it worked, although its taking a little more time to compute.

Comment: Yeah, that does make sense. I'm glad I could help.